# Httpd is not starting with no error

Tags: apache, centos

I'm having a bug for a moment, and I can't figure out what is happening.

When I run :

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

I got the following :

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And here is what I get from systemctl status httpd.service :

```
janv. 05 13:51:14 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
janv. 05 13:51:14 httpd[8566]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf/virtualhosts/S01_namevirtualhost:2
janv. 05 13:51:17 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
janv. 05 13:51:17 kill[8569]: kill: cannot find process ""
janv. 05 13:51:17 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
janv. 05 13:51:17 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
janv. 05 13:51:17 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
janv. 05 13:51:17 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Also, here is the result of apachtctl configtest :

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf/virtualhosts/S01_namevirtualhost:2
Syntax OK
```

This is happening after I tried to renew the SSL certificate of the server, but when I'm putting back the old key files, I have the same issue. I might be missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Any idea ?

Comment: Sounds like no host is defined at all.

Comment: @arkascha but apachectl -S is giving me the right VHosts

Comment: Anything in the error log?

Comment: Oh my... I clearly forgot this file. In httpd error log, there were : [Thu Jan 05 14:50:11.311381 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12726] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Thu Jan 05 14:50:11.311404 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12726] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Indicating that my keys weren't valid, I recreated them, and it's all good now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dusan Bajic I checked the log file... that I forgot.

I post the solution here in case somebody has the same issue :

/var/log/httpd/error_log :

```
[Thu Jan 05 14:50:11.311381 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12726] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Thu Jan 05 14:50:11.311404 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 12726] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

Which informs that the keys for the SSL aren't valid. I recreated them and it's all good now.